# Accessing JSON array within JSON object in VBA Excel using VBA-JSON

Tags: json, vba, excel

I am working on VBA macros to access live data from a website through API calls. I am using VBA-JSON library for it. There are mainly two scenarios when fetching data:

Scenario #1 (we can see `data` is a JSON array):

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "creator_user_id": {
        "id": 162,
        "name": "ASD",
        "email": "email id"

      },
      "user_id": {
        "id": 787878,
        "name": "XYZ",
        "email": "email id"
      },
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

In the scenario 1 I can fetch values within `data` array by using `For Each` loop in VBA Excel through VBA-JSON library.

Scenario #2:

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {

    "id": 123,
    "name": "ABC",

    "options": [
      {
        "id": 119,
        "label": "Name1"
      },
      {
        "id": 120,
        "label": "Name2"
      }
    ],
    "mandatory_flag": false
  }
}
```

But in 2nd scenario I can not access data within `data` array, because JSON `data` array is within JSON object. For example I want the value of `id: 120`  which must return `Name2`, thus I want to access value of `label` which will return `Name2`.

I tried many ways, but can not get it. Please anyone can tell me how this can be done in VBA Excel?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Want to access value of "label" which will return "Name2"

Comment: Could you please post the code or share the link to VBA-JSON library you are using? Post the code you have tried also, note proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Using the VBA-JSON library, you can access the value you want by calling:

```
Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(<yourjsonstring>)
Debug.Print Parsed("data")("options")(2)("label")
```